# Computing the arc length function for given value of a

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question reads as follows:

Compute the arc length function $s(t) = \int_a^t \|\mathbf{r'}(u)\|  \, du $ for the given value of $a$:

$\mathbf{r}(t) = \langle 4t^\frac{1}{2} , \ln(t), 2t \rangle$ for $a=1$

My attempt:

$\mathbf{r}(u) = \langle 4u^\frac{1}{2} , \ln(u), 2u \rangle$ ,

$\mathbf{r'}(u) = \langle 2u^{-\frac{1}{2}}, \frac{1}{u}, 2 \rangle$

$\|\mathbf{r'}(u)\| = (4u^{-1} + u^{-2} + 4)^\frac{1}{2}$

So, $\mathbf{r}(t) = \int_a^t (4u^{-1} + u^{-2} + 4)^\frac{1}{2}  \, du $

$ = \int_a^t \frac{(4u + 1 + 4u^2)^\frac{1}{2}}{u}  \, du$

From here I am not sure how to evaluate this integral, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hint: $(4u + 1 + 4u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=2(u+\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: The answer I get with this integration is $2t + \frac{ln(2t)}{2}$, does this seem correct?

Comment: Not quite.  Gut check: $s(1)$ should be $0$, but it's not for your answer.  I think that's because you forgot about the lower limit of integration.  However, I think your anti-derivative is also slightly wrong.  Multiply through by $2$ first.

Comment: This time around I got $2t + \ln(2t) - 2 - \ln(2)$ .